# Understanding Kubernetes Watch (kubernetes-client/java api)

Tags: java, kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes-client/java api and I want to programmatically get the pod status of all the pods in all the namespaces. My code is based on this [example on Kubernetes java library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/WatchExample.java).

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Watch<V1Pod> watch = Watch.createWatch(
        client,
        api.listPodForAllNamespacesCall(
            null, null, null, null, limit,
            null, null, null, watchTrue,
            null, null),
        new TypeToken<Watch.Response<V1Pod>>() {}.getType());

for (Watch.Response<V1Pod> item : watch) {
    V1PodStatus podStatus = item.object.getStatus();
    String name = item.object.getMetadata().getName();
    String status = podStatus.getPhase();
    String kind = item.object.getKind();
    String details = podStatus.toString();

    System.out.printf("NAME: %s | KIND: %s | STATUS: %s | DETAILS: %n%s%n====================%n", name, kind, status, details);
}
```

**My question is this:** Is `Watch` equivalent to an event handler? This code shows me a list of all the statuses of the pods, but will it automatically "push" more pod status events as they occur in realtime? Or is this only triggered once?

Comment: In my case I am using the `watch = false` and the thread is not released. I mean that I can list the pods but the java application does not exit. Do you know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch is designed to send continuous updates. If you run your program for a while and start/stop something, you will see new updates coming.

I'm not sure it's correct to call it an event handler though. It's a different pattern.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I’m trying to understand what kind of pattern it is and after how much delay it’ll push any new updates. Basically I’m trying to understand if I create the Watch, will I be receiving responses periodically (and if it’s at a scheduled rate or only when something changes), or should I just call the listPodForAllNamespaces as a poll to obtain new statuses at scheduled interval.

Comment: The pattern of Watch API is this:

1. client receives current state as a list
2. client receives incremental updates

It is guaranteed to be consistent, i.e. no events will be missed. I don't know details of the Java API though.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might want to use Watch, List, or if you just want to get IP addresses of all Pods matching certain labels, you might use a simpler headless service and get the IP address by a single DNS query.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the Watch. I created a watch to see all the pods (as in my code above), and I scaled down few pods but I did not see the updates in my Watch. I think I need to play with it more to see how it works. Listing all the pods (& their status) as a polling obviously works.

Comment: You should see all changes if Watch client is implemented correctly. As a quick example of Watch behavior, run `kubectl get pod -w`.